# Compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[{n+1}]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate $L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[{n+1}]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}$

How I approached it and where I get stuck:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[{n+1}]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}nn(\frac{\sqrt[{n+1}]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}-1)$$

Now:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(\frac kn)}=e^{\int_0^1\ln(x)dx}=e^{-1}=\frac1e$$

So $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1e\times n(\frac{\sqrt[{n+1}]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}-1)$. Now this is where I get stuck. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced the factorials with Sterling's approximation: $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n.$  The expression became

$$\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)\left[\sqrt[n+1]{2\pi (n+1)}-\sqrt[n]{2\pi n}\right]+\frac{1}{e}\sqrt[n+1]{2\pi (n+1)}.$$

The second term is easily seen to go to $1/e$.  The first term goes to $0$.  I argue like this:

Let $f(x) = \sqrt[n]{2\pi n}$ and note that the bracketed part of the first term is $f(n+1)-f(n)$.  Invoke the Mean Value Theorem.

$$f'(c) = \frac{ \sqrt[c]{2\pi c}(1-\ln 2\pi c)}{c^2} = f(n+1)-f(n)$$

for some $c$ between $n$ and $n+1$.  Note that $f'(x)$ is increasing, so the bracketed bit is greater than $f'(n)$.  Also note that $f'(x)$ is negative, so the $f(x)$ is decreasing and so the bracketed bit is negative.  We have

$$\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)f'(n)<  \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)\left[\sqrt[n+1]{2\pi (n+1)}-\sqrt[n]{2\pi n}\right]<0.$$

Then see that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{e} \right)\frac{ \sqrt[n]{2\pi n}(1-\ln 2\pi n)}{n^2} = 0$$

so final answer is $1/e$.

Answer (score 3):

You may invoke Stirling's double inequality
$$ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}\,e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}\leq n! \leq \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}\,e^{\frac{1}{12n}} $$
to get that
$$ \sqrt[n]{n!} = \frac{n}{e}+\frac{\log n}{2e}+\frac{\log(2\pi)}{2e}+O\left(\frac{\log^2 n}{n}\right) $$
and
$$ \sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!} = \frac{1}{e}+O\left(\frac{\log^2 n}{n}\right).$$
In other terms, we just have to show that $\sqrt[n]{n!}=\text{GM}(1,2,\ldots,n)$ does not deviate much from $\frac{n}{e}$. Since $n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)$ holds for any $n\geq 2$ we have
$$ n! = \prod_{m=2}^{n}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{n-k}=\frac{n^{n}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k} $$
$$ \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{-k/n}=\exp\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}-\frac{k}{n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right). $$
Over the interval $[0,1]$ the function $x-\log(1+x)$ is non-negative and $O(x^2)$, hence
$$ \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=\exp\left[-\frac{n-1}{n}+O\left(\frac{H_{n-1}}{n} \right)\right]=\exp\left[-1+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)\right]$$
and this proves (in a elementary way) the sharper
$$ \sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!} = \frac{1}{e}+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea in my mind which is to long for a comment and provides another way of computing this limit. However I am not sure whether my attempt is legit or not. Therefore I would just add it now and remove it again in the case that it turns out to be absolute nonsense.

Hence we are dealing with the limit $n\to\infty$ one can use Stirlings formula as a valid approximation for $n!$. Therefore the limit becomes

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)}\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n+1}}-\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2n+2]{2\pi(n+1)}\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)-\sqrt[2n]{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)\\
&\stackrel{?}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)-\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{e}=\frac1e
\end{align}$$

I marked the weak point of my argumentation with $\stackrel{?}{=}$ since I am not sure whether I can do so in this situation or not. The given roots are clearly approaching to one while $n$ is going up to infinity therefore the two fractions as remaining part of the limit are the only thing of relevance. Since my evaluation ends up in the same result as [WolframAlphas](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+for+n+to+infinity+%7B(n%2B1)!%5E1%2F(n%2B1)-n!%5E1%2Fn%7D) I wanted to add my attempt at least.

Comment: By Stolz-Cesaro theorem we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}}1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}$$

and by the root-to-ratio limit, we also have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\times\frac{n^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}$$



$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}=\frac1e$$